# How to create table using json values?

Tags: jquery, json, magento-1.9

Now I am getting json value like this

```
{
    "pricesheet": {
        "100": {
            "2": "10.25",
            "4": "11.2",
            "6": "12.5"
        },
        "200": {
            "2": "11.2",
            "4": "85.25",
            "6": "98.35"
        },
        "300": {
            "2": "65.25",
            "4": "78.65",
            "6": "54.25"
        },
        "400": {
            "2": "87.21",
            "4": "65",
            "6": "98"
        },
        "500": {
            "2": "89",
            "4": "65",
            "6": "48"
        }
    }
```

I want to convert json to create the table like this screenshot

[image: table]
can anyone please help..

Comment: Shouldn't the column headers be 2,4,6 and not 1,2,3?

Comment: column header Must be 2,4,6..